# Exception: Error with message "Class yii\codeception\TestCase not found"

Tags: yii2, codeception

So I am just getting started with Codeception (I know, I am late to the game) and Yii2. There is a error I am running into that I don't seem to get fixed.

**Problem**

1. When I run 'codecept run', I get the error 'Error with message "Class yii\codeception\TestCase not found". Which is strange to me, because when I look for TestCases, I can find multiple TestCases! F.e. in the folders "backend", "console", ..

**Information**

- Codeception has been installed **Globally**
- The CodeCeption version I am using is the version **4.1.12**
- When I run **any** command, the console is giving me the message, "Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception".

What am I doing wrong?

If you guys need any information, hit me up!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please share your code and describe what you have tried in more detail

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `yii\codeception\TestCase` class in your tests?
Have you found it in old tutorial?

`yii\codeception\TestCase` class was provided by [yiisoft/yii2-codeception](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-codeception) package which was abandoned back in 2016.

Use Cest format as documented in https://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Writing-a-Sample-Test